# Speed up SELECT with WINDOW, (PARTITION ... ORDER) with compound index

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE ranking_points  (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  store_id integer,
  book_id integer,
  list_name character varying(255),
  rank integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  storewide boolean,
  yesterday_delta integer,
  best_ever_rank integer,
  best_ever_date date,
  CONSTRAINT ranking_points_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX index_ranking_points_on_book_id_and_created_at
  ON ranking_points (book_id, created_at);

CREATE INDEX index_ranking_points_on_book_id_list_name_and_created_at_desc
  ON ranking_points (book_id, list_name, created_at DESC);

CREATE INDEX index_ranking_points_on_store_id_and_created_at
  ON ranking_points (store_id, created_at);`
```

I am executing the following `SELECT` statement:

```
select distinct book_id, list_name, 
                first_value(created_at) over w as created_at, 
                first_value(rank) over w as rank, 
                first_value(id) over w as id
from ranking_points where book_id in (61,62,63)
window w as (partition by book_id, list_name order by 3 desc)
```

I would expect Postgres to use the `index_ranking_points_on_book_id_list_name_and_created_at_desc` index since it perfectly matches the `partition by` and `order by`, but instead it uses the `index_ranking_points_on_book_id_and_created_at` index. Here is the `explain analyze`:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=895.70..901.41 rows=571 width=42) (actual time=0.740..0.740 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=874.28..888.56 rows=571 width=42) (actual time=0.737..0.737 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=874.28..875.71 rows=571 width=42) (actual time=0.737..0.737 rows=0 loops=1)
              Sort Key: book_id, list_name
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ranking_points  (cost=17.25..848.14 rows=571 width=42) (actual time=0.728..0.728 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (book_id = ANY ('{61,62,63}'::integer[]))
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_ranking_points_on_book_id_and_created_at  (cost=0.00..17.11 rows=571 width=0) (actual time=0.726..0.726 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (book_id = ANY ('{61,62,63}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 0.811 ms
```

You can see that what I'm trying to do is to build a result set consisting of the grouping values and the `first_value` of several fields. My hope was that Postgres could do all of the selection using only the index and then read one record from each group to obtain the `first_value` values. Is that achievable? I have other solutions, but they generate a sequential scan of the table, so that's not very good.

Comment: Is this an actual problem? The query runs in under a millisecond...

Comment: I started to edit to show you the real thing in production (this was in development, the real one has more items in the "where book_id in (...)" phrase, and production is a very much larger database than development), and when I tried it in production it DID use the new index, so apparently I don't have a problem. BTW, without the index the query takes 2 minutes in production; with the index, 1.45 secs.

Comment: `order by 3`? Does that really work?

Comment: Can you try this query instead of yours? I really don't like the distinct in your query:

`select book_id, list_name, 
       created_at, rank, id
from 
  ( select book_id, list_name, 
           created_at, rank, id,
           row_number() over w as rn
    from ranking_points where book_id in (61,62,63)
    window w as (partition by book_id, list_name order by created_at desc)
  ) as t
where rn = 1 ;`

Comment: And this one:

   `select t.book_id, t.list_name, 
           t.created_at, t.rank, t.id
    from 
      ( select distinct book_id, list_name
        from ranking_points where book_id in (61,62,63)
      ) as dt,
      LATERAL
      ( select book_id, list_name, 
               created_at, rank, id
        from ranking_points 
        where book_id = dt.book_id and list_name = dt.list_name
        order by created_at desc
        limit 1
      ) as t ;`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that Postgres does use the index, if you have enough records. This was against my development database, which is relatively empty. In production without the index, I get this from EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=186849.60..187449.78 rows=200061 width=48) (actual time=129567.598..129568.987 rows=1903 loops=1)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=185149.08..186349.45 rows=200061 width=48) (actual time=129182.770..129460.868 rows=186023 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=185149.08..185249.11 rows=200061 width=48) (actual time=129181.497..129228.725 rows=186023 loops=1)
              Sort Key: book_id, list_name
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25441kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ranking_points  (cost=3813.71..181625.99 rows=200061 width=48) (actual time=67.821..128210.717 rows=186023 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (book_id = ANY ('{61,62,63,64,66,70,78,270,301,298,398,402,414,15485,15416,2767,6922,6920,6974,18002,9122,15444,65,1774,4939,18331,22828,22209,19841,22402,22841,18232}'::integer[]))
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_ranking_points_on_book_id_and_created_at  (cost=0.00..3803.70 rows=200061 width=0) (actual time=55.568..55.568 rows=186023 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (book_id = ANY ('{61,62,63,64,66,70,78,270,301,298,398,402,414,15485,15416,2767,6922,6920,6974,18002,9122,15444,65,1774,4939,18331,22828,22209,19841,22402,22841,18232}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 129573.021 ms
```

With the index, I get this:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=193464.14..194108.37 rows=214744 width=48) (actual time=1446.685..1447.571 rows=1903 loops=1)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=191638.82..192927.28 rows=214744 width=48) (actual time=1091.394..1349.506 rows=186027 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=191638.82..191746.19 rows=214744 width=48) (actual time=1091.381..1136.297 rows=186027 loops=1)
              Sort Key: book_id, list_name
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25441kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ranking_points  (cost=3772.47..187835.22 rows=214744 width=48) (actual time=58.064..221.151 rows=186027 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (book_id = ANY ('{61,62,63,64,66,70,78,270,301,298,398,402,414,15485,15416,2767,6922,6920,6974,18002,9122,15444,65,1774,4939,18331,22828,22209,19841,22402,22841,18232}'::integer[]))
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_ranking_points_on_book_id_list_name_and_created_at_desc  (cost=0.00..3761.74 rows=214744 width=0) (actual time=44.349..44.349 rows=186027 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (book_id = ANY ('{61,62,63,64,66,70,78,270,301,298,398,402,414,15485,15416,2767,6922,6920,6974,18002,9122,15444,65,1774,4939,18331,22828,22209,19841,22402,22841,18232}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 1450.444 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have many rows with the same `list_name` per `book_id` and many rows per combination in your table `ranking_points`, which is very inefficient.

```
book_id              ... 32     
(book_id, list_name) ... 1903
total rows           ... 186023
```

You defined the column `list_name character varying(255)`, which indicates it's a potentially long string. (A limit of 255 has no performance benefit in Postgres, btw.) If you store that in a halfway normalized form, you'll get smaller storage and *much* faster results:

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  book_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, book    text NOT NULL
-- you probably have that ...
);

CREATE TABLE listed (
  listed_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, book_id   int REFERENCES book
, list_name text NOT NULL
, UNIQUE (book_id, list_name)  -- provides needed index
--  potentially more?  
);

CREATE TABLE ranking_points (
  ranking_points_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, store_id   integer
, listed_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES listed
, rank       integer
, created_at timestamp
, updated_at timestamp
, storewide  boolean
, yesterday_delta integer
, best_ever_rank  integer
, best_ever_date  date
);

CREATE INDEX index_ranking_points_listed_created_at
ON ranking_points (listed_id, created_at DESC NULLS LAST);
```

If `created_at` can be NULL like absence of a `NOT NULL` constraint suggests, use `DESC NULLS LAST` as sort order (which won't hurt either way)

*If* you can get index-only scans out of it, it would pay to add the otherwise useless columns `rank`, `id` to the index.

#### Query

```
SELECT l.book_id, l.list_name 
     , r.created_at, r.rank, r.id
FROM  unnest('{61,62,63}'::int[]) b(book_id)
JOIN  listed l USING (book_id)
    , LATERAL (
   SELECT created_at, rank, id
   FROM   ranking_points
   WHERE  listed_id = l.listed_id
   ORDER  BY created_at DESC NULLS LAST  -- match index
   LIMIT  1
   ) r;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb06c/1) without test data.
Should be substantially faster. Detailed explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)